# How to add content at the start of page powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a sample script, which reads a file and add a text in front of text loaded and write back as new file with combined data.

Problem is the original lines are replaced with spaces.

```
$r = Get-Content -Path "C:\\Users\\UReddy\\Desktop\\travelling - Copy (2).txt"
#echo $r

foreach($i in $r){
   #echo $i
}

$te = "Hello `r" + $r

echo $te

$te | Out-File "C:\\Users\\UReddy\\Desktop\\travelling - Copy (3).txt"
```

Input file:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_77nz20nIXo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m55EtpNqpDY&t=196s
```

Output File:

```
Hello 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_77nz20nIXo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m55EtpNqpDY&t=196s
```

How to retain the original line endings in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have join the elements in `$r` with newline.

```
$te = "Hello `n" + ($r -Join "`n")
```

This is because by default *[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1)* [returns an array of ***newline-delimited strings***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1#example-6--get-raw-content)

Comment: But,  $te =  $r + "Hello `r"  is not having any issue. Only adding from top getting this issue. If this is the case, why it is not working there?